# PHP array_rand not working properly when randomizing more then 1 random arraykey

Tags: php

My code randomizes an array index which consists 3 values for example.

```
$t1 = array("6","7","8");    
$randomized = array_rand($t1, 3);
echo $t1[$randomized[0]];
```

only outputs the value 6.

```
$randomized = array_rand($t1, 2);
echo $t1[$randomized[0]];
```

only outputs the value 6 or 7.

However this works :

```
    $randomized = array_rand($t1, 1);
    echo $t1[$randomized];
```

this works and outputs 6,7 or 8

I don't get it and YES I did execute the function like 10 times to see if its not just coincidence.

Answer (score 3):

[`array_rand()`](http://php.net/array_rand) according to the documentation...

> Picks one or more random entries out of an array, and returns the key (or keys) of the random entries.

There is no mention in the documentation that it randomizes the order of the randomly chosen keys. What you apparently want is [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php).

So try something like this:

```
$t1 = array("6","7","8");
$randomized = array_rand($t1, 3);
shuffle($randomized);
echo $t1[$randomized[0]];
```

Answer (score 2):

**This is not a bug.**

Since 5.2.10, PHP no longer shuffles the extracted keys, they're always ordered.

Because of this ordering, extracting 2 keys from an array comprising 4 values can be done in only 6 ways:

```
4! / (2! * 2!)
```

This is contrary to your expected 12:

```
4! / 2!
```

Therefore, extracting all keys out of the array can only be done in one way and thus effectively yields `array_keys($array)`;

My advice would be to use [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/shuffle) instead.

Comment: +1. This makes more sense. And `shuffle()` sounds like the correct tool for this purpose.